# How to programmatically click a link in IE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem specific to IE with this function:

```
function downloadFileFromUserControl(filename) {
    var name = filename.split("/");
    var fName = name[name.length - 1];
    console.log("IE speaking, I'm just going to take a little nap during this request");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fName;
    link.href = filename;
    link.click();
    console.log("Oh, I'm late to the party?? Back to sleep I guess");
}
```

In Chrome this function works perfectly, I use this to download PDF files from hyperlinks. No errors, it just will post to the console.

Is there some additional code IE needs to make this work? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if a DOM element in IE needs to be inserted into the DOM in order to process a click event or if you need to do the click like `setTimeout(function() {link.click()}, 20);` or both.

Comment: It does run the function, but no error. It does nothing but post to the console

Answer (score 0):

After the element is created, use the `element.appendChild()` or `element.insertBefore()` method to insert it to the `document`.

It is how it works, refer [w3c reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Comment: Trying this gives me a script hierarchy error. This case is sort of similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071968/jquery-throws-script5022-hierarchyrequesterror-when-attempted-to-append-a-jquer . This is a webforms app (it's maintenance, leave me alone!). This JS function is on my 'Master' page. The function is being called from a user control (.ascx) file.

Comment: Ok, so have you tried the solution provided in the similar question mentioned by you

Answer (score 0):

IE does NOT support the "download" attribute only newer browsers ie. Edge, you need to be careful with using new HTML5 functionality in old browsers, most of the time you need to add some sort of "fallback" for this particular case I'd suggest:

```
    if (typeof link.download !== typeof undefined && link.download !== false) {
       var message = document.getElementById('Some <Span> ID Here').innerHTML('Right-click and select "Download Linked File"');
    }
```